# How to Creat 3D objects

Tags: java, 3d

I want to draw 3D shapes and picture in java but i don't know how do it.
please help me or introduce a good book.
thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [Java 3D API Tutorial](http://java.sun.com/developer/onlineTraining/java3d/) is a good place to start. You can work through the examples starting with `HelloJava3D`.

Comment: if java applets is needed for 3d graphics?

Comment: @mehdi you don't necessarily need an Applet. You can also use a plain JFrame.

Answer (score 1):

Check out [JOGL](http://download.java.net/media/jogl/www/). There are some really good projects running on top of it.

Comment: if java applets is needed for 3d graphics?

Comment: If you want to ask extra questions it's best to edit your original question.